# Python: failed to get all the text in all the <span> tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have looked through the stackoverflow but still don't find a solution for that.
Here is the html file I need to handle:

```
......<span ><span class='pl'>Director </span>: <span class='attrs'><a href="/celebrity/1022571/" rel="v:directedBy">James</a></span></span><br/>
<span ><span class='pl'>Actor</span>: <span class='attrs'><a href="/celebrity/1022571/">Tom</a></span></span><br/>
<span class="pl">Countries:</span> USA <br/>
<span class="pl">Language:</span> English <br/>......
```

There are many `span` tags in the file.
Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

record=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
spans=soup.find_all('span')
for span in spans:
    record.append(span.text)
```

I use the code mentioned above, and I got 2 problem.
The first one is I got double `Director` and `Actor` in the result because they are in 2 `span` tags. The second problem is that I can't get the text before `<br>` tag. I don't want to use that following code:

```
soup.find("span", text="Language:").next_sibling
```

because for every `br` tags I need to add that code to my project, it's annoying.
Do you have some elegant solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write something generic, you would still need to locate the next sibling tag/text node with `next_sibling` or `find_next_sibling`.

Here is the code that would handle both cases - when there is an element after the label and the text node:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for label in soup.find_all("span", class_="pl"):
    value = label.find_next_sibling("span", class_="attrs")
    value = label.next_sibling.strip() if not value else value.get_text(strip=True)

    label = label.get_text(strip=True).strip(":")
    print(label, value)
```

Prints:

```
Director James
Actor Tom
Countries USA
Language English
```